# Gettting retweets by searching whole original tweet by Search API

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

I would like to search the whole text of a particular tweet to get the retweets of the original tweet. The search pattern would be like following

```
"text" include:retweets
```

Do you think that it will work well? Or do you have any better idea than this?

I have already known twitter4j and its functions have `twitterObject.getRetweets(original tweet id)` to get retweets but this function returns only the last 100 retweets. In fact, I would like to crawl all or most of them somehow.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem. Describe your problem in more detail or include a minimal example in the question itself. Read more: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @EelLee Looks fine to me. The OP wants to get the retweets from a tweet without being limited by `twitter4j`'s 100 retweet limit. As a side note, he *does* include a minimal code example.